# How to add buttons and color line on top to the "ExpansionTile Card" widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I use the ExpansionTile Card widget to display the history of orders, when you click on this widget, additional information should appear (but I think this is not difficult to do). The problem is that I don't know how to place the edit button in the widget itself (before it is deployed). I want to do as in the photo. Maybe someone knows how to do it??? I will be grateful for my help. Here is my code (what is commented is the code that I tried to make but without the ExpansionTile Card. But it does not fit because it gave me an error)

My image(as i want)

[image]

Image(now)

[image]

My code widget

```dart
    _listItemColumn({
        required String name,
        required String date,
        required String status,
        required String id,
      }) {

        return Column(

          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                  Margins.medium, Margins.tiny, Margins.tiny, Margins.small),
              child: ExpansionTileCard(
              title: Text(name),
              subtitle: Text(date),
              trailing: SizedBox.shrink(),

              // Row(
              //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              //   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              //   children: [
              //     Expanded(
              //       child: Column(
              //         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              //         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              //         children: [
              //           Text(
              //             name,
              //             textAlign: TextAlign.start,
              //             maxLines: 2,
              //             style: const TextStyle(
              //               fontSize: FontSize.medium,
              //               fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              //             ),
              //           ),
              //           Container(
              //             height: Margins.tiny,
              //           ),
              //           Text(
              //             date,
              //             textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              //             maxLines: 1,
              //             style: TextStyle(
              //               color: Colorz.textGray,
              //               overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              //               fontSize: FontSize.small,
              //             ),
              //           ),
              //         ],
              //       ),
              //     ),
              //     Column(
              //       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              //       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              //       children: [
              //         Material(
              //           color: Colorz.white,
              //           child: InkWrapper(
              //             splashColor: Colorz.lighterGray,
              //             child: IconButton(
              //                 alignment: Alignment.center,
              //                 icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              //                   Img.listItemMenu,
              //                 ),
              //                 onPressed: null
              //             ),
              //             onTap: () {
              //             },
              //           ),
              //         ),
              //         Text(
              //           status,
              //           textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              //           maxLines: 1,
              //           style: TextStyle(
              //             color: _colorStatus(status),
              //             overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              //             fontSize: FontSize.tiny,
              //           ),
              //         ),
              //       ],
              //     )
              //   ],
              // ),
            ),
        ),
      ]
        );

      }
    }
```

That is, I can somehow add this code to the header and subtitle:

```
 Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Material(
                        color: Colorz.white,
                        child: InkWrapper(
                          splashColor: Colorz.lighterGray,
                          child: IconButton(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                Img.listItemMenu,
                              ),
                              onPressed: null
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        status,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        maxLines: 1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: _colorStatus(status),
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          fontSize: FontSize.tiny,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
```

Comment: You can use `trailing` for this

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, you are right,)) it helped, and could you help with the colored strip on top???

Comment: the top level green?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes, that strip is colored above the widget

Comment: Ok I will give a try, can you share the link

Comment: @YeasinSheikh link to what?)

Comment: should I update my answer or you will provide another question including your snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh  this is the same question, and the code is the same (with a widget)

Comment: OK check the seond part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `trailing: SizedBox.shrink(),` with

```dart
trailing: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

If you need text, wrap it with column widget.

To have border on top, you can nested containers like

```dart
final borderRadius = BorderRadius.only(
  topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
  topRight: Radius.circular(24),
);

return Column(children: [
  Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5), //control green
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.green,
        borderRadius: borderRadius,
      ),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: borderRadius,
        ),
        child: ExpansionTile(
```

Comment: you can check more about [UI](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)